# Position view outside of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I want to position views outside of a `ConstraintLayout` to animate them with a sliding animation. I've tried setting contraints like `constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` but the `View` stays inside the container.

Note that I want to achieve this with constraints to use built-in animations, not with in-code animations.

Any idea how I could do this ?

I'm using `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'`
  with Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7

This is a simple xml file that should place the view outside of the container :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But this is the result
[image]

Comment: I have never tried it but what about varing the bias from 0 to 1?

Comment: please share your xml

Comment: Post which version of `ConstraintLayout` you are using. Make sure that you aren't defining additional constraints that will pull the view back into the layout. Also, seeing the XML would be helpful.

Comment: I added xml and `ConstraintLayout` version

Comment: I was able to make this work by setting padding and clipToPadding="false" I have an ImageView that I position horizontally by percent relative to a Guideline and I need it to work in the range of 0 - 1. When at the right/left edge of the ConstraintLayout the imageView was being clipped in half. By setting rightPadding and leftPadding for the ConstraintLayout to half the width of the ImageView it's not being clipped anymore  (and the percent positioning is still working).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0-beta1; It works as expected in `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0-beta3.

Update to `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0-beta3. I will also note that you need to constrain your view horizontally by doing something like the following.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent" />
```

On a side note, negative margins are not accepted in `ConstraintLayout`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984909/how-to-achieve-overlap-negative-margin-on-constraint-layout) Stack Overflow question regarding negative margins and `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it solved this particular problem, but know that it brings back an old problem where the `ConstraintLayout` is messed up inside a nestedScrollView

Comment: @DavidSeroussi I am sorry to hear that another issue has popped up. You can post a question addressing that nested scroll view issue with the XML that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In every view you can use negative margin, which will put the view outside of the parent view, and then set the clipping parameters.

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

this will make the view not to clip.

Comment: Negative margins don't work in constraint layouts which were mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I got another way to solve the problem:

1.Add a anchor(`anchor_left`) `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`.

2.Add `YourView` `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/anchor_left"`

That's it!

code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor_left"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <YourView
        android:id="@+id/ll_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/anchor_left"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: anchor view also worked for me. I just control the anchor view instead the view instead. putting a constraint directly to the `parent` makes it go outside the parent but it sticks to only that position

Answer (score 0):

What I did is:

- created a view of **0dp** height inside the ConstraintLayout, e.g. "fakeView"
- placed the new fakeView anchored at Top of the ConstraintLayout

when I need to hide a View, translate it outside the constraint..

- change the constraint of the view you want to hide, in order to have BOTTOM connected to the Top of the FakeView.

I think you can use same technique to move object on the left of the fakeview or on the right.

Answer (score 0):

One trick would be to set negative margin for the side you want, in the `ConstraintLayout` itself. This requires that other views that have constraint to that side be offset:

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="-48dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_next_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_previous_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```