# Move View out of Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, android-constraintlayout

[image: Image that I want to be cut]

I want to move my `ImageView` so it will be half way out of the `ConstraintLayout` (parent one)
You can imagine this as I make negative margin in my `LinearLayout`

*What I have is an Image and it should be cut as on picture, so only button side of the image should be displayed on the actual device. Other part should be cut off.*

Here is a part of my layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:src="@drawable/someImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, is there any good way to do that?

Comment: How is that useful?

Comment: I am not sure what you want (half way out of the ConstraintLayout)

Comment: @Xenolion I've updated my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position view outside of ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770659/position-view-outside-of-constraintlayout)

Answer (score 13):

So I found the solution.
Basically you need to make a translation of the image out of its container.

```
android:translationY="-22dp"
```

Comment: For a background image, I also used `android:translationY` successfully but I also had to remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from my `ImageView`.  Before removing it, the position would be inconsistent on different device screen sizes.

Answer (score 5):

Add a guide line and say that your ImageView should be above that guidelines for example this code will make everything appear like your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="163dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To position the `ImageView` halfway outside parent enforce the vertical constraints by setting `layout_height` to `0dp`. To maintain the appropriate size of the `ImageView` set the `dimensionRatio` to `1:1`. The code will look like this (note that parent `ConstraintLayout` now has `layout_height` matching parent):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/someImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the image inside of the Linear Layout.

```
<LinearLayout....>

    <ImageView..../>

</LinearLayout>
```

And add attribute called **clipChildren** and make it **true**.

Answer (score 0):

One trick would be to set negative margin for the side you want, in the `ConstraintLayout` itself. This requires that other views that have constraint to that side be offset. The right button in the images is below the `ConstraintLayout` and hidden under the bottom bar:

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="-48dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_next_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_previous_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by adding View inside the ConstraintLayout and give it some margin.

View provides background to ConstraintLayout.

ConstraintLayout must be of transparent background.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView/>
```