# Animate view off Screen in android Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have a TextView inside a Constraint Layout. I am trying to animate in a way that the view goes off the screen from top. This is what I did so far,

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)holder.mView;
constraintSet.clone(layout);

constraintSet.clear(R.id.txt_PackageTitle,ConstraintSet.TOP);
constraintSet.clear(R.id.txt_PackageDescription,ConstraintSet.TOP);  
constraintSet.clear(R.id.txt_PackageTitle,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM); 
constraintSet.clear(R.id.txt_PackageDescription,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

constraintSet.setMargin(R.id.txt_PackageTitle,ConstraintSet.TOP,-600); 
constraintSet.setMargin(R.id.txt_PackageDescription,ConstraintSet.TOP,-1200);

ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
transition.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
transition.setDuration(600);                
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout,transition);
                    constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
```

Now this code only moves the contents to the very top of the view, its not going out of the view and getting disappeared.

How can I do this with constraint layout?

Comment: first make view go out of the screen than remove/dealocate it.

Comment: use collapsing layout to get whatever you want

Comment: @Mikhail how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of clearing the bottom constraint of the `TextView`, try constraining its bottom to the top of the `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
constraintSet.connect (R.id.txt_PackageTitle, 
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 
            PARENT_ID, 
            ConstraintSet.TOP);
```

Now when the view is animated, it should slide off the top edge.

Negative margins are not supported with `ConstraintLayout` as is noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984909/how-to-achieve-overlap-negative-margin-on-constraint-layout/43016512#43016512).