# Adjust my button slightly downward in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I got the following layout, as well you can see my "View More" button is aligned exactly **vertically center/middle** of the bottom edge line.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_content"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_content"
```

Now, what if I want to push my "View More" button slightly downward for about 2% of its height or 2dp for example.

I've tried `android:layout_marginTop="50dp"` makes no different

`app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"` makes no different either.

What else any "constraint solution" I can do, **besides the old school method**:

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` (apply on `btn_view_more`) and then hardcode the `marginBottom` and push upward

I know this is one of the solutions but, I'm interested to know if any constraint related solution available that I'm not aware of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_transparent_round_corner"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iv_close"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_circle"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_content" />

    <air.com.my.companyname.util.font.InterRegularButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_view_more"
        style="@style/ButtonSolidBlue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="View More"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_content" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There's a way but I don't know if it is what you want to achieve in the end. Instead of constraining your 'view more' button top to the bottom of image view, you can constraint it as top to the top of image view. This will make button centered to your imageview. now use vertical bias with fraction values more than 1 like '1.02' etc.

Comment: i've tried this, but it seems that , 1 or 1.02 is contraint to bottom, or I'd say move downward, I've tried to put -0.2 , but it seems not possible, bias 0.0 will stick to top (bottom of `iv_content`)

Comment: value greater than 1 caused part of button move out of screen

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the button XML:

```
android:translationY="2dp"
```

This will move the button down by `2dp`. The drawback to this method is that any views constrained to the top or bottom of the button will *not move* with the `2dp` shift since the shift occurs *post layout*. The button will still be 100% clickable and otherwise functional in its new position.

*ConstraintLayout* does not support negative margins which would be a nice solution. For other solutions look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984909/how-to-achieve-overlap-negative-margin-on-constraint-layout).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `iv_content` ImageView:

```
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
```

It will give you the look you want.
If it messes with your image in the ImageView, you can take 2dp off of the bottom margin of the `iv_content` like so:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `btn_view_more`

```
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_content"
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: if i not mistaken this will make it lays somewhere inside of white area, and never touch on content area

Comment: Where should be the button positioned actually?

Comment: same with the screenshot but slightly moving down (part of the button should be still overlaying the content)